# Timthumb 403 forbidden issue

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

I am trying to use timthumb in one of my projects and it doesn't seem to be working and i searched all over and couldn't get the issue sorted.

Here is the url of my site

http://192[dot]185[dot]98[dot]213/~ancoradc/wp-content/themes/AncoraDC/timthumb.php?w=150&h=150&zc=1&src=http://192[dot]185[dot]98[dot]213/~ancoradc/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/fluke.jpg

The file has 755 permission and cache is also 755 but i don't why this isn't working. Can anyone please advice me what could be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/inc/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/banner.png&amp;w=600&amp;h=150" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
```

At first try inside theme, put the timthumb.php file and image file in a specific location of theme. Then set the path properly for timthumb's location as well as image in above code. Hope it will work.